# how to run sencha web application without compiling

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Hello I am new to Sencha. I have created a test application using sencha cmd. When I have to run it i have to compile it. Is there any way so that I can run the application without compiling and without starting web server.

Comment: Sencha app watch starts a microserver on http://localhost:1841. You can use that in the browser. But you can't execute PHP in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your uncompiled application, but you always have to use a web server to access your application, because there are problems with AJAX without a web server.

What I did to get this working:

- I installed a local web server as a service (in my case it's IIS, but Apache or any other should work as well)
- My local web server root directory points to my git repo directory.
- In that git repo, I have the `myapp-dev` directory containing the uncompiled ExtJS application, the `myapp` directory, and the bin directory containing my backend API.
- The app.json file in `myapp-dev` tells Cmd to compile into the `myapp` directory:

  ```
  "output": {
       "base": "../myapp",
       "appCache": {
           "enable": false
       }
   },
  ```

That way, the relative paths to the server API are the same for both the uncompiled and the compiled version, e.g. `../api/GetSettings` points to the same path for both versions.

I can now open `localhost/myapp-dev/index.html` in the browser and get the uncompiled version, or I can open `localhost/myapp/index.html` in the browser and get the compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

You can just place your app files in a directory inside a server root, then open the index.html directly.

While it is desirable to compile it for production (to get a better performance), it is certainly not necessary if you just want to have your app in "development" mode all the time.